# Member of AD Group Not Getting Permissions in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, adfs

Dealing with the following issue. First, the scenario:

- UserA account exists in Domain1
- UserA is a member of GroupX in Domain2
- Domain2 trusts Domain1 (one-way)
- Domain1 and Domain2 both sync with Office 365 via ADFS
- There are 3 other Domain1 users in GroupX.
- GroupX has Contribute permissions to a folder in a library on a SharePoint Online (SPO) site.

And now the issue: The other 3 users from Domain1 in GroupX get the permissions GroupX is assigned in the SPO library, but UserA does not. Using Check Permissions in SPO for the other 3 users shows their permissions coming from the GroupX assignment, but UserA shows "none" when checking the folder GroupX has access to. When checking from the site collection level, UserA shows "Limited Access."

Any thoughts? Thanks.